# how can I implement an algorithm that can slice a texture to multiple sprites by transparency?

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite

I want to implement the feature that Unity has: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html
"With the slicing type set to Automatic, the editor will attempt to guess the boundaries of sprite elements by transparency", what is the easiest way to implement this?

Comment: Searching for someone on [careers 2.0](http://careers.stackoverflow.com). No, to be serious...questions on StackOverflow must show an attempt to solve the problem by yourself (with code, research, something). If you just post a requirement your question will be downvoted and closed.

Comment: Plus the question is too broad and it leaves anyone wondering: why on earth would anyone want to do that if Unity has this feature built-in? That often indicates a fixation to work on a given problem without analyzing requirements and evaluating alternate solutions.

Comment: IMHO, this is a legit question. A quick googling did not return any usefull results. Also, why not use the sprite editor? For example this might be needed at runtime or as a tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to find bounding boxes of your sprites. For this you will have to mark pixels as used and not yet used.

In pseudocode:

```
set every transparent pixel as used
// now you should have separate sprites marked as unused

while at least one pixel not used:

  position=find first unused pixel

  bounds=flood fill from position as used, saving bounds of the fill

  if bounds intersect any previous found sprite position:
    throw error

  save bounds as a sprite position
```

---

Example ([sprite source](http://opengameart.org/content/elvisjohnny-cash-type-sprite-sheets)):

First you have a sprite sheet with a transparent background:

[image: example-step-1]

Then you fill the background as used:

[image: example-step-2]

Then find the first unused pixel:

[image: example-step-3]

Then flood fill the sprite, the bounds of your flood fill are the bounds of your sprite.

[image: example-step-4]

---

You might want to tinker with the first step so you give margin to the sprites - this way the separation will work better and you will not have any dangling pixels left over.

[image: example-separation]

Comment: perfect solution! Why I haven't thought the flood fill which is a such  a common and useful algorithm! it is very useful in boundary finding such as generating path finding graph in 2D, or marking navmesh detour using voxels in 3D, etc.